# Como verificar se o Texto Random do String[] é verdadeiro ou não

Tags: java, android-studio

Estou criando um jogo no *Android Studio* e preciso comparar se o texto lançado na tela é aquele ou não, para então apresentar a dica.

Ps: Ao usar o `equals` obtenho tudo verdadeiro mostrando a mensagem sempre, o que não é o que quero.

```
Private String[] obj = { bola, sapato, caderno }

Private String[] dica = { redondo, preto, folhas }

novoobj.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Random randomico = new Random();
            int objaleatorio = randomico.nextInt(perguntas.length);
            textoobj.setText(obj[objaleatorio]);

 novadica.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Random randomico = new Random();
            int dicaaleatoria = randomico.nextInt(dica.length);
            textodica.setText(dica[dicaaleatoria]);
```

Aqui entra o `if` que não esta dando certo. Pois quero que somente se o `obj` for o da posição `0`, ele lance a dica. Mas nesse caso abaixo lança com qualquer valor que coloco. Já tentei por o texto também, mais deu erro no Java.

```
        if (!(obj.equals(0)){
            textodica.setText(dica[dicaaleatoria]);
```

Ou seja, o que quero, se texto na tela for bola por exemplo então escreva a dica aleatória. Redondo, por exemplo.

Comment: Você consegue compartilhar a classe inteira que está esse trecho ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (obj[0].equals(textoobj.getText())){
    textodica.setText(dica[dicaaleatoria]);
```

Consegui resolver dessa forma. Fica aqui, caso alguém precise.

Answer (score 1):

Primeira coisa que você vai precisar é usar o ***import java.util.Arrays*** , logo abaixo tem uma função que verifica uma string do array obj e caso ela exista vai no array de dica buscar a dica certa. Coloquei a string "caderno" como exemplo porém você pode usar ela como parâmetro da função. 
Você pode substituir a chamada do seu if pela função buscarDica();

```
import java.util.Arrays;

private String[] obj = { "bola", "sapato", "caderno"};
private String[] dica = { "redondo", "preto", "folhas" };

private  String buscarDica(){
    int index = Arrays.asList(obj).indexOf("cardeno");
    if (index > 0 && index < dica.length)
        return dica[index];
    else 
        return "Não tem dicas";
}
```

Comment: fabio, Boa tarde. Sou novo no Java, não entendi bem o que quis dizer com validar. esse seu cód faz o que?. É só eu colocar o if na frente? Normalmente se usa equals, porém já tentei e não adianta. To doido já. Rsrs

Comment: Boa tarde, você precisa fazer duas coisas pra o código funcionar, a primeira é importar a classe Arrays mais informações sobre ela aqui https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Arrays a segunda coisa é usa o trecho do código dentro que eu coloquei na resposta dentro do seu IF, ele a função índexOf vai retornar o primeiro elemento do seu array no caso uma String, nele você pode usar o equals, vou tentar ajustar o código pra melhorar.

Comment: Vou fazer uns ajustes na respostas pra ficar melhor, assim que tiver um tempo, acredito que não ficou muito clara!

Comment: fabio, pelo que entendi, você quer que eu crie uma public Classe Array, porém a validação é dentro da Classe onClick, não sei se aceitaria 1 class em outra. A ideia é que se ao clicar a palavra do Array for == x, Então mostre na tela a dica y.

Comment: fabio, agradeço muito a ajuda, esse trecho de cód. seu me ajudou, mas acredito que o que eu quero fazer não é possível no java pelo que vi em alguns fóruns. Acho que só mudando o cód todo pra dar certo. Pegando o seu cód de ex: eu teria que por  o que o int index recebeu o valor ou o róprio index, dentro do evento onClick dica.